# How do I find out which version of a driver is included in a kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I need to find out which driver/module version is contained in a kernel which isn't installed. Is there a document in the source that contains this or something listed online that haven't been able to find?

Comment: You're going at this the wrong way... Read [this](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3278/how-can-i-be-assured-that-my-issue-can-be-helped-here?cb=1).  Use the tools I listed in the troubleshooting section, then from the output tell us what isn't working.

Comment: Which module are you interested in? Why do you need the version?

Comment: @eyoung100 It isn't a matter of troubleshooting. I was asked by one of our dedicated Red Hat resources which driver version is provided by the latest kernel found at kernel.org. Again, this isn't for running kernels. I know how to obtain that information. I need to know how to determine what a kernel will provide prior to installation. Release notes that list driver versions or similar documentation.

Comment: @michas the fnic driver. I was asked to determine which driver version is provided in the source downloaded from kernel.org.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `modinfo` command to give you all kind of information about a given module.

For example:

```
$ modinfo bluetooth
filename:       /lib/modules/3.17.4-1-ARCH/kernel/net/bluetooth/bluetooth.ko.gz
alias:          net-pf-31
license:        GPL
version:        2.19
description:    Bluetooth Core ver 2.19
author:         Marcel Holtmann <marcel@holtmann.org>
srcversion:     4D63C2C41C55E984E7057A5
depends:        rfkill,crc16
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.17.4-1-ARCH SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           disable_esco:Disable eSCO connection creation (bool)
parm:           disable_ertm:Disable enhanced retransmission mode (bool)
```

However most of the time you will not find any explicit version, because the module is simply the one contained in your kernel source tree.

Comment: This is for the running kernel. I'm interested in knowing what any kernel provides. For instance, if I download the source for a kernel how can I tell what it will provide?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "latest kernel", do you mean latest stable, latest longterm, or latest mainline?  Are you looking for a non-RC kernel, or an RC kernel?  Since I don't know these details, I'll assume you meant latest non-RC mainline kernel, which is currently 4.5.

For kernel 4.5, all you have to do is browse [the 4.5 git tree](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/?id=refs/tags/v4.5) down to [drivers/scsi/fnic](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/scsi/fnic?id=refs/tags/v4.5) and look at [fnic.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/scsi/fnic/fnic.h?id=refs/tags/v4.5):

```
#define DRV_NAME            "fnic"
#define DRV_DESCRIPTION     "Cisco FCoE HBA Driver"
#define DRV_VERSION         "1.6.0.17a"
```

While the release of kernel 4.5 is pretty far removed in time from when you asked your question, the same technique described here would apply to kernels closer to the timeframe of your question, such as [kernel 3.17](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/scsi/fnic/fnic.h?h=v3.17) or [kernel 3.18](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/scsi/fnic/fnic.h?h=v3.18).